# Typed property User::$DateCreated must be an instance of DateTime, string used

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

My main question is if there is support for object properties in PDO?

I'm looking to go straight from my sql results to the User class.  I know I can create an interpreter-type class but I was hoping for a straightforward solution.  Can anyone help, please?

The error is as follows:

```
Typed property User::$DateCreated must be an instance of DateTime, string used
```

This is my php class

```
class User
{
    public int $UserId;
    public string $Username;
    public string $Email;
    public string $PassHash;
    public DateTime $DateCreated; // problem area
    public bool $Active;
}
```

And this is how it looks in the db

```
mysql> desc Users;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| UserId      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| Username    | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| Email       | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| PassHash    | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| DateCreated | datetime     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| Active      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0                 |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I'm calling it with this function, which is breaking because it's trying to push a string in into a DateTime property

```
public function GetUsers() : array
{
    $sql = "SELECT UserId, Username, Email, DateCreated, Active FROM Users";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User"); 
}
```

However, when I run this code, it returns a DateTime object, just like you'd expect.

```
public function GetUsersThisWorksTho() : array
{
    $sql = "SELECT DateCreated FROM Users";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "DateTime");
    // this works. It actually casts the result as a php DateTime object
}
```

Comment: On a quick investigation, [discovered that SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-datetime-objects-using-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) has a PDO attribute `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_DATETIME_TYPE`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be available for the MySQL PDO driver. Curious that the DateTime solo query is cast as hoped. Can't find any documentation explaining why that happens. o_O

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be after is an [Object Relational Mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM), of which exist a few publicly available libraries for PHP. [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/) being a popular one.

Answer (score -1):

It seems PDO doesn't convert objects dynamically.

As in `fetchAll()` the constructor is executed after filling the class properties you can check in the constructor if the `DateCreated` property is a string so you can convert in a `DateTime` object using `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()`.